# How do Loki's 'other paths' between realms work?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor*, it's revealed that Loki knows of non-Bifrost ways to go from one realm to another.  In *Thor: The Dark World*, we see one of them in action.  How do these inter-realm paths work?  What makes these locations able to transport people between realms?

Comment: The proposed duplicate asks about the existence of paths. The answers discuss that without going into the mechanics of them. This question is more focused on why the paths work.

Comment: @phantom42 - Keen's answer below would make an excellent answer to the duplicate listed above.

Answer (score 3):

In the DVD commentary for *Thor: The Dark World*, this is discussed.  There are places that have shards of the rainbow bridge material (i.e. the rainbow crystal).  During the scene in *Thor: The Dark World* where they use one, you can see these shards in the cave walls.

Loki knows the location of some of these rainbow bridge deposits.  He also knows how to jury-rig a wormhole using the rainbow bridge material there.  This then enables him to go from one realm to another, by creating a quick and dirty wormhole.

Comment: Since this depends on the bridge being shattered (courtesy of Thor in the first movie), does this mean that Loki, at the start of the first movie, had to have smuggled the 3 ice giants into Asgard using the Bifrost without anyone (Heimdall and Odin specifically, but also anyone else who might notice a huge beam of light at an odd time) somehow knowing?

Comment: @Ellesedil No, these paths existed at the start of *Thor*.  It's implied that the rainbow bridge material just exists naturally in places.